# How to automap with a specific condition in C# .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, dto

I want to automap a fill workerCategory key in my specific DTO but I don't know how to do. I got no errors when I build the solution but when I make API calls it trigger an error.

Could you help me?

```
public class WorkerRD
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
        public string Iso { get; set; }
        public string Sexe { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int WorkerCategoryKey { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TrWorkerToWorkerCategory> trWorkerToWorkerCategory { get; set; }
    }

CreateMap<TUser, WorkerRD>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Firstname,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Firstname)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Lastname,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Lastname)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Email,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Email)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Phone,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Phone)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Sexe,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Sexe)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Address,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Address)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Postcode,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Postcode)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Locality,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.Locality)
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.WorkerCategoryKey,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.TrWorkerToWorkerCategory.Where(tr => tr.IsDefault == true).Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey))
                ).ForMember(
                    dest => dest.trWorkerToWorkerCategory,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.TrWorkerToWorkerCategory.Where(tr => tr.IsDefault == true))
                );
```

My porblem is here. I want to select workerCategoryKey (integer) and map it in WorkerCategoryKey.
But it doesn't work.

```
.ForMember(
                    dest => dest.WorkerCategoryKey,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.TrWorkerToWorkerCategory.Where(tr => tr.IsDefault == true).Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping you have doesn't work because you can't simply map a collection (`.Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey)`) to a single value (`dest.trWorkerToWorkerCategory`). An easy way to understand this is by doing a similar mapping manually:

```cs
List<int> source = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
int destination = source;
```

That doesn't make any sense, but that's essentially what you're telling AutoMapper to do with your current mapping for `WorkerCategoryKey`.

With that said, it's not easy to say exactly what you need to do, because it depends on the data. But whatever it is, you need the source to be a single `int`. For example, if the source is always going to be a collection of the same `WorkerCategoryKey`, then you could just get the first item from `.Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey)`:

```cs
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.WorkerCategoryKey,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TWorker.TrWorkerToWorkerCategory.Where(tr => tr.IsDefault == true).Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey).First())
```

Comment: Hi @devNull I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Cannot convert bool to int.

Comment: @Mathlan89 Just updated it, should be `.Select(cat => cat.WorkerCategoryKey).First()`

Comment: fantastic, it works, this was just what I needed :-) Thanks a lot for your help! I was nearly to the solutionbut I do not set the First() :)